# Verifying calls to Func when passed as a parameter to an injected interface when running a unit test

Tags: c#, moq

I am unsure about the best way to verify that a method is called when a Func is invoked.  Using the code below - I want to ensure that the injected IThirdPartyWrapper calls the DoSomething on the injected IInjectedInterface.  Is there an alternative to this?

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var thirdPartyWrapperMock = new Mock<IThirdPartyWrapper>();
        var injectedInterface = new Mock<IInjectedInterface>();
        injectedInterface.Setup(x => x.DoSomething()).Verifiable();

        bool called = false;
        thirdPartyWrapperMock.Setup(x => x.Execute(It.IsAny<Func<Context, IInjectedInterface>>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>())).Callback(() =>
            {
                called = true;
            });

        var tester = new ConsumerClass(thirdPartyWrapperMock.Object, injectedInterface.Object);

        tester.Execute();

        // The below call fails
        injectedInterface.VerifyAll();
        // called is false
        Assert.True(called);

    }

    public class ConsumerClass
    {
        private readonly IThirdPartyWrapper _thirdPartyWrapper;
        private readonly IInjectedInterface _injectedInterface;

        public ConsumerClass(IThirdPartyWrapper thirdPartyWrapper, IInjectedInterface injectedInterface)
        {
            _thirdPartyWrapper = thirdPartyWrapper;
            _injectedInterface = injectedInterface;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _thirdPartyWrapper.Execute(x => _injectedInterface.DoSomething(), new Dictionary<string, object>());
        }
    }


    public interface IThirdPartyWrapper
    {
        TResult Execute<TResult>(
            Func<Context, TResult> action,
            IDictionary<string, object> contextData);
    }

    public interface IInjectedInterface
    {
        string DoSomething();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean something like the Compiler warning/handling for out parameters? Or a Runtime Exception?

Comment: I mean verifying the correct method is called when running the unit test.

Comment: I think your setup `thirdPartyWrapperMock` is wrong, actually 2 errors: 1) you return type of the function is `string` not `IInjectedInterface` 2) you didn't invoke the `Func` in your callback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to verify `Func` you need to invoke it from `Callback`. Try to setup it like this:

```
thirdPartyWrapperMock
    .Setup(x => x.Execute(It.IsAny<Func<Context, string>>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>()))
    .Callback<Func<Context, string>, IDictionary<string, object>>((func, dict) => func.Invoke(new Context()));
```

You will notice a few differences compared with your original approach:

- The return value of the function is `string` since `DoSomething()` returns `string`.
- The function has been actually invoked within the callback, otherwise, you cannot verify it. The `Context` is not important at all since you are not using it.
- Using this setup the `called` is not needed anymore since `VerifyAll` will ensure the method is invoked.